# Getting content between two divs

Tags: c#, html, xpath

I need to get only the strong tags between those two `DIV`s.
Using XPath, I've already tried the following:

```
/*/strong[count(following::div)]
//strong[count(preceding::div)=1]
```

And many others.
I want to extract the content between these

```
    <div style="width:100%;background-color:#F0F0F0;"><strong style="color:#FF6600;">Subseção Foz do Iguaçu</strong></div>
<br /><strong>1ª Vara Federal de Foz do Iguaçu</strong>
<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="controlador.php?acao=consulta_processual_resultado_pesquisa&txtValor=2004.70.02.002782-1&selOrigem=PR&chkMostrarBaixados=S&selForma=NU&txtDataFase=01/01/1970&hdnRefId=1aa56964d02a2ddc2562a7087d0b7d45&txtPalavraGerada=cabh">1. CARTA PRECATÓRIA - 2004.70.02.002782-1 (PR)</a>
<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="controlador.php?acao=consulta_processual_resultado_pesquisa&txtValor=2002.70.02.006023-2&selOrigem=PR&chkMostrarBaixados=S&selForma=NU&txtDataFase=01/01/1970&hdnRefId=1aa56964d02a2ddc2562a7087d0b7d45&txtPalavraGerada=cabh">2. EMBARGOS À EXECUÇÃO - 2002.70.02.006023-2 (PR)</a>
<br />
<br />
<div style="width:100%;background-color:#F0F0F0;"><strong style="color:#FF6600;">Subseção Curitiba</strong></div>
<br /><strong>6ª Vara Federal de Curitiba</strong>
<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="controlador.php?acao=consulta_processual_resultado_pesquisa&txtValor=2001.70.00.023051-6&selOrigem=PR&chkMostrarBaixados=S&selForma=NU&txtDataFase=01/01/1970&hdnRefId=1aa56964d02a2ddc2562a7087d0b7d45&txtPalavraGerada=cabh">3. PROCEDIMENTO COMUM - 2001.70.00.023051-6 (PR)</a>
<br />
<br /><strong>06A VF DE CURITIBA (Antiga)</strong>
<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="controlador.php?acao=consulta_processual_resultado_pesquisa&txtValor=2001.70.00.019792-6&selOrigem=PR&chkMostrarBaixados=S&selForma=NU&txtDataFase=01/01/1970&hdnRefId=1aa56964d02a2ddc2562a7087d0b7d45&txtPalavraGerada=cabh">4. PROCEDIMENTO COMUM - 2001.70.00.019792-6 (PR)</a>
<br />
<br />
<div style="width:100%;background-color:#F0F0F0;"><strong style="color:#FF6600;">Subseção Foz do Iguaçu</strong></div>
<br /><strong>1ª Vara Federal de Foz do Iguaçu</strong>
<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="controlador.php?acao=consulta_processual_resultado_pesquisa&txtValor=92.10.10851-5&selOrigem=PR&chkMostrarBaixados=S&selForma=NU&txtDataFase=01/01/1970&hdnRefId=1aa56964d02a2ddc2562a7087d0b7d45&txtPalavraGerada=cabh">5. PROCEDIMENTO COMUM - 92.10.10851-5 (PR)</a>
<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="controlador.php?acao=consulta_processual_resultado_pesquisa&txtValor=87.10.18327-2&selOrigem=PR&chkMostrarBaixados=S&selForma=NU&txtDataFase=01/01/1970&hdnRefId=1aa56964d02a2ddc2562a7087d0b7d45&txtPalavraGerada=cabh">6. EXECUÇÃO DE TÍTULO EXTRAJUDICIAL - 87.10.18327-2 (PR)</a>
<br />
<br />
```

I want the content between divs

Subseção Foz do Iguaçu

**1ª Vara Federal de Foz do Iguaçu**

   1. CARTA PRECATÓRIA - 2004.70.02.002782-1 (PR)

   2. EMBARGOS À EXECUÇÃO - 2002.70.02.006023-2 (PR)

Comment: Have you tried using regex? A pattern like this should work, although I'm not sure how c# treats regex capture groups: (?:<strong>)(.*)(?:<\/strong>)

Comment: Are you expecting the `1ª Vara Federal de Foz do Iguaçu` as output? If not can you please add expected output.

Comment: By extract do you mean to say you want to put it elsewhere or remove it entirely? Does it need to be xPath?

Also do you mean the contents between the strong tags? Expected output would help.

Comment: the provided XML is not well-formed (invalid), but why you don't use just /div/strong as XPATH expression please provide expected output

Answer (score 0):

I could only come up with this monstrosity

```
//div[1][@style="width:100%;background-color:#F0F0F0;"]/strong | //strong[1][following-sibling::div[@style="width:100%;background-color:#F0F0F0;"]] | //a[1][following-sibling::div[@style="width:100%;background-color:#F0F0F0;"]] | //a[2][following-sibling::div[@style="width:100%;background-color:#F0F0F0;"]]
```

output is

```
<strong>Subseção Foz do Iguaçu</strong>
<strong>1ª Vara Federal de Foz do Iguaçu</strong>
<a>1. CARTA PRECATÓRIA - 2004.70.02.002782-1 (PR)</a>
<a>2. EMBARGOS À EXECUÇÃO - 2002.70.02.006023-2 (PR)</a>
```

to select everyone use this other monstrosity

```
//div[@style="width:100%;background-color:#F0F0F0;"]/strong | //strong[following-sibling::div[@style="width:100%;background-color:#F0F0F0;"]] | //a[following-sibling::div[@style="width:100%;background-color:#F0F0F0;"]]
```

Hope it helps

Comment: The problem is that I kinda need a stop for xpath, I need to scrap everything

Comment: if it doesn't, can you provide the full page HTML?

Comment: I need to get the content between the first two divs in my question, however I dont know how many might come if I change the input

Comment: can you put the expected result in the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following XPath-1.0 expression

```
//strong[preceding-sibling::div[contains(@style,'width:100%')] and following-sibling::div[contains(@style,'width:100%')]]
```

to get all the `<strong>` tags between the two marked `DIV`s.
**With your input, the output is:**

```
1ª Vara Federal de Foz do Iguaçu
6ª Vara Federal de Curitiba
06A VF DE CURITIBA (Antiga)
1ª Vara Federal de Foz do Iguaçu
```

for the `text()` values and

```
<strong>1ª Vara Federal de Foz do Iguaçu</strong>
<strong>6ª Vara Federal de Curitiba</strong>
<strong>06A VF DE CURITIBA (Antiga)</strong>
<strong>1ª Vara Federal de Foz do Iguaçu</strong>
```

for the elements.

Comment: //strong[contains(preceding-sibling::div/@style,'width:100%') or contains(ancestor::div/@style,'width:100%')]

Comment: edited a bit of your xpath, this selector might work

Comment: @Valga: I don't know what you were trying to achieve with your comments.

Comment: i thought that he wanted all the strong elements, not only the ones inside the div, that's why i posted that (and i used your answer to create that xpath, didn't want to steal your work)